# Error warning doubts

Tags: iphone

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{    NSMutableString *message=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            message = @"Result: canceled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            message = @"Result: saved";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            message = @"Result: sent";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            message = @"Result: failed";
            break;
        default:
            message = @"Result: not sent";
            break;
    }
```

I am using the above code for mailcomposer. When compiled it gives the warning `incompatable pointer types assigning to NSMutableString from NSString`. I believe this happens when we use NSString instead of NSMutableString. How can I solve this?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not appending anything to "message" apart from the switch case, use an NSString instead of an NSMutableString.

If you have to use a mutable string, instead of

```
message = @"Result: cancelled";
```

use

```
[message appendString:@"Result: cancelled"];
```

Comment: @lostln Transit case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            [message appendString:@"Result: cancelled"];
            break; right???

Comment: @ICoder yes. I just meant to post the code related to the warning. Everything else remains the same. And the same change ([message appendString:]) would be made in each case.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [setString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/setString%3a) method

```
[message setString:@"Result ..."];
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning new value, you have to append the values like,

```
[message appendString:@"Result: canceled"];
```

Finally you can use `message`.

Answer (score 2):

Here,I could see the case of potentially memory leak ... As you are creating `NSMutableString` object using **init** and then assigning a `NSString` object.

So, Would advice your to use `appendString` method of `NSMutableString`.